# IList versus DataTable

Tags: c#-3.0

What is the difference between IList and DataTable and which one to use while fetching the records from Db and storing in to them..so that they can be used onto my Presentaion layer.

Comment: As a matter of fact you should use none of them. You should use strongly typed collections such as `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

`IList` is an interface.

`DataTable` is a concrete class that models a database table.

The differences are large as are the use cases - the answer depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: But which one is far optimized to use?

Comment: @Rupa Mistry, it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Rupa Mistry - Your question makes no sense without much more information. `IList` _can't_ be used directly. It is an interface. `DataTable` is for modeling database tables. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

`IList` is used when you have not used larger and complex structured (Class) data.

`DataTable` can be optimized by primary key and also it can be filtered, sorted, etc.

So, typically you should prefer `DataTable` over `IList`.

`IList` should used only when you are sure it is what you want.